# ReactJs: How to turn a map loop into a for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops, for-loop

Ive been wondering what the best way to approach this is, if I should go through the elements of my array with a For loop or Map.

**This is my array:**

```
    templates = [
        {
            title: "Grocery List",
            description: "Description of what this things does so the reader can have info of",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 0,
        },

        {
            title: "Shopping Space",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
            id: 1,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel Planning",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753885/travel.png",
            id: 2,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 3,
        },
    ];
```

Which is processed by my TemplateList component that maps each element. I would like to convert this to a **For loop** but I dont know how I should approach it. Also, Is it better to have a For loop in this case?

**TemplateList:**

```
export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL: string;
    id?: number;
};

type Props = {
    templates: Template[];
};

const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
            {templates.map((item) => (
                <TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                    key={item.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TemplateList;
```

This is my **TemplateCard** component:

```
type Props = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    classNameToAdd?: string;
    classNameOnSelected?: string;
};

const TemplateCard = ({ title, description, img, classNameToAdd, classNameOnSelected }: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
    };

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }
    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>
                {title}
                {selected ? <BlueCheckIcon style={blueCheck} className={styles.blueCheck} /> : null}
            </div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

TemplateCard.defaultProps = {
    classNameOnSelected: styles.selected,
};

export default TemplateCard;
```

Comment: a for loop doesn't return anything at all. So even if you wanted it wouldnt work

Comment: @kevin the OP could use a for loop to populate another array an return that array. It does not make a lot of sense and I think is less readable, but it can be done.

Comment: So then he'd still have an array that he'd need to map over in order to generate the jsx, or am i misunderstanding something? @secan

Comment: @kevin a react component can return an array of components and each item will be rendered; you can see a very simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/95L7nyfe/

Comment: Thank you for the example in fiddle. will leave it as it is now.

Comment: @secan aah yes i see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const number = [1, 2, 3, 4];

//using map example
const square_map = number.map(num => num * num);
console.log('using map', square_map);

//using forEach example
const square_Foreach = [];
number.forEach(num => square_Foreach.push(num * num));
console.log('using forEach', square_Foreach);

//using for example
const square_for = [];
const number_length = number.length;
for (let i = 0; i < number_length; i++) {
  square_for.push(number[i] * number[i])
};
console.log('using for loop', square_for);
```

Answer (score 1):

the standard way of doing it is to use `map` since it will return a component for Each element by default i don't see any use of using `forEach` or standard for loop specifically in react jsx